# Trying to check the current time falls inside a range of start/end time using momentJS (UTC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Trying to check if the current time is between start and end time.

Everything is in UTC, any ideas?

Works

```js
shiftCurrentTime = moment.utc().format('hh:mm');
console.log(shiftCurrentTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Doesn't work

```js
shiftStartTime = moment.utc('20:00').format('hh:mm'),
  shiftEndTime = moment.utc('05:00').format('hh:mm'),
  shiftCurrentTime = moment.utc().format('hh:mm');

console.log(shiftCurrentTime.isBetween(shiftStartTime, shiftEndTime));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing between moment objects and their string representation (given by [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/))

You have to [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) your string into moment object specifying format, since `HH:mm` is not a known [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

You can call [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) on the moment object, while calling it on the formatted string gives you error.

Here a complete working example:

```js
var shiftStartTime = moment.utc('20:00', 'HH:mm'),
shiftEndTime = moment.utc('05:00', 'HH:mm'),
shiftCurrentTime = moment.utc();

console.log(shiftCurrentTime.isBetween(shiftStartTime, shiftEndTime));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome stuff dude :)